# Why returened values of form are null in MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, view, model

I try to update a record .I use validation in this view but always

> ModelState.IsValid = false

I search on the internet and found that I should check errors with this code :

```
 var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

[image]
Now I can not understand that what is problem?
In this image you can see that all parameters are null.
[image]

Please advice.
View:

```
    @model TravelEnterAdminTemplate.Models.LG.ResturantModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditRestaurant";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@*fck Editor*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Adminex/js/fckEditor/fckeditor.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var sBasePath = '@Url.Content("~/Content/Adminex/js/fckeditor/")';
        var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('Restaurants_Description');
        oFCKeditor.BasePath = sBasePath;
        oFCKeditor.Height = 450;
        oFCKeditor.Width = 800;
        oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
        //----------------------DescriptionEn---------------------
        var oFCKeditorEn = new FCKeditor('Restaurants_DescriptionEn');
        oFCKeditorEn.BasePath = sBasePath;
        oFCKeditorEn.Height = 450;
        oFCKeditorEn.Width = 800;
        oFCKeditorEn.ReplaceTextarea();
    }
</script>
<div class="container">
    <h4>ویرایش رستوران</h4>
    <hr />

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">


            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Restaurants.id)



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.RestaurantName, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "RestaurantName" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.RestaurantName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.RestaurantName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "Address" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.City.Country.NameFa, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "CountryId" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
                    <div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.City.NameFA, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "CityId" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("CityId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.Tell, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "Tell" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.Tell, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.Tell, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "Title" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.InsertDate, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "InsertDate" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.InsertDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.InsertDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.Summary, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "Summary" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.Summary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.Summary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "Description" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.LocationX, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "LocationX" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.LocationX, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.LocationX, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.LocationY, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "LocationY" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.LocationY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.LocationY, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3  pull-right">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.Website, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "Website" })


                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.Website, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control website" } })

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.Website, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-5  pull-right">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @lablefor = "IsActive" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.IsActive)

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*@
            <fieldset dir="ltr" class="fieldsetEn">
                <legend>English Content</legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="checkbox checkboxEn">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.IsEnglish, htmlAttributes: new { @Labelfor = "IsEnglish" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.IsEnglish)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.IsEnglish, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.RestaurantNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @Labelfor = "RestaurantNameEn" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.RestaurantNameEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.RestaurantNameEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.AddressEn, htmlAttributes: new { @Labelfor = "AddressEn" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.AddressEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.AddressEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.TitleEn, htmlAttributes: new { @Labelfor = "TitleEn" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.TitleEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.TitleEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.SummaryEn, htmlAttributes: new { @Labelfor = "" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restaurants.SummaryEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.SummaryEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restaurants.DescriptionEn, htmlAttributes: new { @Labelfor = "DescriptionEn" })
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Restaurants.DescriptionEn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restaurants.DescriptionEn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>

            @{
        string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageEdit"];
            }
            <div class="row text-right">
                @foreach (var item in Model.PhotoTables)
                {

                    <text>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-wrapper pull-right">
                            <div class="image-wrapper">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(path + item.PhotoName)" alt="" class=" img-responsive" />
                                <img class="delimg" src="~/Content/Adminex/images/delete-icons.png" id="@item.Id" alt="حذف تصویر" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </text>

                }
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="submit" value="ذخیره تغییرات" class="btn btn-info btn-block" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<script src="~/Content/Adminex/js/ajax/Restaurants_Edit.js"></script>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryValidation")
}
```

Model:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace TravelEnterAdminTemplate.Models.dbModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Restaurant
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string RestaurantName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Tell { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string LocationX { get; set; }
        public string LocationY { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int Visitor { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string RestaurantNameEn { get; set; }
        public string AddressEn { get; set; }
        public string TitleEn { get; set; }
        public string SummaryEn { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionEn { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VisitorEn { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnglish { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try posting your view and viewmodel code

Comment: The model in your view is `ResturantModel` but the model in your POST method is `Restaurant` (they need to be the same!)

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use Code like this for debugging. (written from memory)

```
var errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < ModelState.Keys.Count; i++)
{
     var value = ModelState.Values.ElementAt(i);
     if value.Errors.Any()
     {
          foreach (var error in Value.Errors)
          {
               errors.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                 (ModelState.Keys.ElementAt(i),
                  error.Message ??  error.Exception.Message);
           }
      }
 }
```

This should help you diagnose which model elements are causing validation errors.

A common reason for server side validation errors is that a non-nullable int or Guid Id field is included in the model but is either not included in the view, or is hidden and / or not populated.

Comment: You right. I use this code and found that  error.ErrorMessage  is my massages  in Mete Data for validation  and error.Exception.Message is null.In other words All returned values in form is null.  Now How to fix this?

Comment: The point is to identify the field that is invalid, and fix the issue. A quick look at the view and model suggests that it could be your CategoryId.

Answer (score 0):

that's not how you post though.

your post method should be very simple, something like :

public async Task Post(ModelClass someName)

so you basically have a model class. That class needs to be decorated with [DataContract] which needs a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization

Each property in that class that you want to be able to send as part of a post needs to then have a DataMember tag on it. This way the default serialization used by the MVC engine will kick in and accept your post as long as the names passed by the form match those in the model exactly. This applies especially when we work with WebApi. For pure MVC work we don't need those tags

Always do model validation first :

if (!ModelState.IsValid) then return an error code

every validation item you have on your model properties needs to happen before the ModelState will be valid.

Here's a basic example which I wrote a few years ago, maybe it will help :

[mvc article](http://eidand.com/2013/07/28/mvc-basics-part-3/)